# Default Assignment Operator Segfault

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, move-constructor

I'm getting a segfault when using a locally created object after another locally created object of the same type is assigned to it.

The object has defaulted move and copy constructors as well as a default assignment operator.

The object inherits from a virtual class (not pure virtual). Both the object and its parent are defined in a .dll that I'm linking in.

The object and its parent contain only primitive types.

I believe that I have linked the .dll correctly. And I'm simply constructing the one object then trying to use it.

My question is simply, would there be a problem with the default copy/move constructor or default assignment operator if:

1. The class had virtual functions
2. The class had a parent with virtual functions
3. The class's parent was defined in a .dll
4. The class was defined in a .dll

Comment: Maybe the class's parent contains pointers and doesn't follow the rule of three?

Comment: There's no such thing as "virtual class" or "pure virtual class" . Did you mean virtual inheritance, or that the base class with some virtual functions (maybe with at least one pure virtual function)

Comment: @MattMcNabb The parent class can be constructed. There are no pure virtual methods. But there are virtual methods. It does define a default constructor implementation.

Comment: Is there any chance you could give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Have you tried moving the classes out of the dll (to test whether their dll-ness is actually a part of the problem)? How about removing the virtual functions one by one?

Comment: The short answer to the question: no, there is no problem.

Comment: @Beta Yeah that's my next step. As far as a MCVE, I will work on simplifying, but a straightforward answer to the question posed above is what I want, not someone to debug my code for me.

Comment: The straightforward is "no, I don't see how those things would cause problems, provided they were done correctly".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's the answer I wanted. I didn't think there was a problem. I just wanted to confirm. maybe one of my inputs to the constructed object is corrupted. I'll have to look at that. If you wanna put that in an answer I'm down to accept.

Comment: @Beta That's what I believed, I just wanted to hear there wasn't a corner case that everyone but me knew.